# ionic 2 - Installation of native plugin facebook

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i am installing facebook plugin. when i run command `sudo npm install --save @ionic-native/facebook` i get error: `unmet peer dependency ionic-native/core4.4.2 invalid`

my system info:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
Node       : v6.12.0
npm        : 3.10.10
OS         : OS X El Capitan
Xcode      : Xcode 8.1 Build version 8T46g
```

Comment: what is the version of `ionic-native/core` in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

```
1.> install ionic-native $ npm install ionic-native/core --save 
2.> Which type of peer dependency error is occurred  update an npm according to it Don’t use $ npm install Note - : becoze it install
current version & type script & other dependency is not compatible
with current version’s.
3.> so, to update npm use this command npm install npm@4 -g, here 4 =  which version u want to install(like 3,4,5 & etc).
4.> Then install peer dependency, which is not present. ex -  $ npm install ionic-native/@4.2.0 --save
```